# Compiler errors with std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct foo{
  int _val;
};

int main(){
  list<foo> A;
  foo B;
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    B._val=i;
    A.push_back(B);
  }
  list< reference_wrapper < foo > > C(A.begin(),A.end());
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use std::reference_wrapper to hold references to type "foo" but when I do this I get a very peculiar compiler error:

```
>In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/list:63,
from ref_wrapper.cpp:4:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_list.h: In member function \u2018void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<foo>, _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<foo>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<foo> >]\u2019:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_list.h:577:   instantiated from \u2018std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::list(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Alloc&) [with _InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<foo>, _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<foo>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<foo> >]\u2019
ref_wrapper.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1361: error: no matching function for call to \u2018std::list<std::reference_wrapper<foo>, std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<foo> > >::push_back(foo&)\u2019
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_list.h:919: note: candidates are: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<foo>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<foo> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_list.h:924: note:                 void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<foo>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<foo> >]
```

It is impossible to discern what is going on. I have tried the same code on VS 2010 and it worked. I am wondering why it's not working for g++

The command I entered in terminal was:

```
 g++ -std=gnu++0x reference_wrapper_test.cpp -o reference_wrapper_test
```

Comment: `no matching function for call to \u2018std::list, std::allocator > >::push_back(foo&)`. That explains why MSVC accepts it. It has that evil extension.

Comment: variable names are weird.

Comment: Alright so how do go about accomplishing the above functionality with g++?

Comment: @XYZ Update to g++ 4.7: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1tmztV$0 (4.6 seems to work,too.)

Comment: gcc 4.4.6 is just ages old.

Comment: @chris: The `push_back(foo&)` is just the *call* signature, i.e. the compiler trying to call a function `push_back` with an lvalue `foo`. This has nothing to do with that particular (evil) extension, since a conversion from `foo` to `reference_wrapper<foo>` is necessary in any case, which should produce an rvalue. I think it's just GCC 4.4.6's `reference_wrapper` that doesn't have the right constructor.

Comment: @Xeo, Oops, for some reason, I thought it was making a reference from a temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could update your compiler .

See the Link : http://liveworkspace.org/code/3mVcGp$6